# i load html page in jquery dialog but when i close dialog and again open dialog then its giving following error

Tags: jquery

i load html page in jQuery dialogue but when i close dialogue using close button and again open dialogue then its giving following error:

```
Error: cannot call methods on dialogue prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'isOpen'
```

my code

```
$("#enterRunnerPositionDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    position: 'center',
    title: 'Enter Runner Position Selection',
    draggable: false,
    width: 1000,
    height: 900,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        var html = "";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "AdminController",
            data: {
                overlayScreenNo: 25,
                objectName: 'horseNo'
            },
            success: function (response) {
                var parseJSON = eval('(' + response + ')');
                var success = parseJSON.success;
                var status = parseJSON.status;
                if (success == true && status == 200) {
                    displayRunner(parseJSON.result);
                } else {
                    //alert(parseJSON.msg);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    $("#enterRunnerPositionButton").click(function () {
        $("#enterRunnerPositionDialog").load('runnerPositionSelection.html', function () {
            //$("#enterRunnerPositionDialog").dialog("open");
        });
        if ($("#enterRunnerPositionDialog").dialog("isOpen")) {} else $("#enterRunnerPositionDialog").dialog("open");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I wish I had the HTML and access to the AJAX page but since I don't you'll have to test this out and give me feedback.  A lot of errors in the code, fixed below.  Missing brackets, objects being called too many times (likely the source of the error you got), etc.

### Try this:

```
$dlg = $("#enterRunnerPositionDialog");
$btn = $("#enterRunnerPositionButton");
$dlg.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    position: 'center',
    title: 'Enter Runner Position Selection',
    draggable: false,
    width: 1000,
    height: 900,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        var html = "";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "AdminController",
            data: {
                overlayScreenNo: 25,
                objectName: 'horseNo'
            },
            success: function (response) {
                var parseJSON = eval('(' + response + ')');
                var success = parseJSON.success;
                var status = parseJSON.status;
                if (success === true && status === 200) {
                    displayRunner(parseJSON.result);
                } else {
                    //alert(parseJSON.msg);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
$btn.click(function () {
    //$("#enterRunnerPositionDialog").load('runnerPositionSelection.html', function () {
    //$("#enterRunnerPositionDialog").dialog("open");
    //});
    if ($dlg.dialog("isOpen")) {
        return;
    } else {
        $dlg.dialog("open");
    }
});
```